# Which coordinate system is this data in? Kilometers from the South Pole (90° S) and the 180th meridian

Tags: coordinate-system, spain

I'm using some data which, after some hours trying to figure out what its numbers mean, I found that its points are represented by two quantities: kilometers from the South Pole (90° S) and kilometers from the 180th meridian.

For example, these are some points I have with their equivalent lat-long degrees representations (I've rounded them):

```
16384,20642   41.6° N, 0.0° E
16384,20203   38.8° N, 0.0° E
15759,20203   38.8° N, 6.9° W
```

I'm not sure that the second quantity represents the kilometers from the 180th meridian. That's because as you go North the arc in the sphere should become smaller, but as you see in the first and second point in the example, although they're both in the same meridian both have the same value.

The software that is using this representation is *SigPac* (a well-known GIS for agriculture in Spain). They use this coordinate system internally to get parcels data.

Is there any projection that uses that reference system or something similar to what I've described?

Comment: Rather than guessing, it would be best to ask the provider.

Comment: @Vince Yes, but as this is a public service and administration in Spain is so slow... you know. I just wanted to know if this is a common coordinate system (I'm not an expert on this area). Anyway, I will probably try to contact them in order to get that information.

Comment: These coordinates look like they could be pixel coordinates of a map tile. 16384 = 2^14, so the map tile could be 2^15 pixels wide from -180° to 180°, and use for example a Mercator Projection, or Web Mercator. That is only guesswork but it could be worth testing it with the exact values, at first glance it looks like it could fit with Web Mercator.

Comment: @FSimardGIS Yes, that's the system they are using! With your information and googling a little bit more, the coordinates here (http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/, at zoom level 15) correspond exactly with the ones I have. Thanks!